# Scala: How can I mock this function using Mockito?

Tags: scala, akka, mockito

I am wanting to test one of my akka actors, it uses slick to get the information from the database. In my actor I have this bit of code

```
CardStationPermissions.retrieveByStationID(stationID).foreach(card => {
```

I want to know how can I mock that function to change the output instead of relaying on whats in the database?

Comment: Instead of directly calling `retrieveByStationID` function on `CardStationPermissions` object, refactor object to a trait and mixin the trait with your actor code. You can find really good articles with searching **cake pattern** on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really difficult to mock things that are being called in a static way (in this case, a call on an `object` as opposed to an instance of a `class`).  When you need to be able to mock and test things like this, I tend to agree with Mustafa's suggestion that creating a trait to represent the relevant methods to mock.  A simple example would look as follows:

```
case class MyObject(id:Long)
trait MyDao{
  def getData(input:String):List[MyObject] = ...
}
object MyDao extends MyDao

class MyActor extends Actor{
  val myDao:MyDao = MyDao

  def receive = {
    case param:String => sender ! myDao.getData(param)
  }
}
```

Here you can see that I have a trait to represent my dao methods (only 1 for this example) and then I mix that trait into a scala object as the default instantiation of that trait.  When I setup my dao in my actor, I explicitly type it to the trait so that I can substitute a mock impl of that trait later.

So then if I wanted a simple test showing mocking, it could look something like this (via specs2):

```
class MyActorTest(_system:ActorSystem) extends TestKit(_system) 
  with Specification with Mockito with ImplicitSender{

  def this() = this(ActorSystem("test"))

  trait scoping extends Scope{
    val mockDao = mock[MyDao]
    val actor = TestActorRef(new MyActor{
      override val myDao = mockDao
    })
  }

  "A request to get data" should{
    "pass the input to the dao and return the result to the sender" in new scoping{
      mockDao.getData("foo") returns List(MyObject(1))
      actor ! "foo"
      expectMsg(List(MyObject(1)))
    }
  }
}
```